# xloper12 variable xltype = str using wide characters

Tags: excel, xll

I am trying to register some functions and have success up until the length of my string exceeds 255. I have written the below function to cycle through the list of parameters and convert the L"xxparametersxx". For any string <255 characters it works fine but when I get to the 256 character string it does not enter the corresponding code for the # of characters in the first entry. Would anyone have any ideas here please?

Joe

Function Code:

```
XLOPER12 CreateXLOPER12FromWStr(LPCWSTR cInput)

    XLOPER12 lpx;

    size_t len;

    len = wcslen(cInput);   wchar_t* lps = (wchar_t *)malloc((len + 2) * sizeof(wchar_t));

    lps[0] = (wchar_t)(len+2);

    wmemcpy_s(lps + 1, len, cInput, len);   lpx.xltype = xltypeStr;     lpx.val.str = lps;

    return lpx;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function above appears valid (except missing braces!) and I can run it,  although I'm not sure why you put `len+2` into `lps[0]`: just the string length is sufficient.  You may be hitting other limitations downstream, if you are using `xlfRegister`:

- The total length of comma-separated parameter names must be < 256 chars
- Help strings must be < 256 chars
- Function name must be < 256 chars

This is despite the `XLOPER12` type allowing for considerably longer strings.

I don't recommend that anyone else use the C API directly: rather use [my library xlOil](https://github.com/cunnane/xloil) which hides implementation details like the above and adds COM, GUI & RTD support.  Or use [Keith's xlladdins](https://github.com/xlladdins/xll).

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for responding. I have a number of functions which I have written all with success. The issue I think is you first bullet point, which supposedly was not corrected when the usage of "long" strings was implemented.

I did look at both your and Keiths add-in, and appreciate the work done by both of you, guess im just a gluten for punishment and went down the road of doing it myself. Thus far this is the only snag I have faced.

Comment: Good luck!  You may bump into the old 256 char string limit in other places, for example some custom formats (like the Accounting one) have this limit.